# windows forms listbox sorted by date

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

I have a windows forms List box connected to a Data Source that lists dates which is a column in my database. I would like to either sort by most recent DB entry or by most recent date first. 
 Currently it is sorted by number which is default I think:

```
5/1/15
5/11/15
5/4/15
5/5/15
```

and on goes the list

I have it bound to a database column that has the date in it which is typed into a textbox.

How can I sort this data to start with the most recent date/ DB entry?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you not order by Date Desc in the SQL that populates your Datasource? This way it can easily be changed and your datasource will receive and display this data.

Comment: by the way that's not sorted at all by default I would recommend showing us your sql command and from there we can help you to write a proper query to order the date field for you `ASC or DESC`

Comment: What is the datatype of the database column that's bound to the listbox?

Comment: If you are familiar with Linq you could do it using linq http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943887/order-list-by-date-and-time-in-string-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by Date Desc in the SQL that populates your Datasource? This way it can easily be changed without rebuilding your application and seperates the data logic from your application. Your datasource will receive and display the data based on what is returned by the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the easiest answer was posted my a few of you, changing the datasource from varchar to datetime. Thanks again!